# Expression bodied Function Weird Behavior

Tags: c#, .net, async-await, nullreferenceexception, expression-body

When I am using

```
    var frontPage = await GetFrontPage();

    protected override async Task<WordDocument> GetFrontPage()
    {
        return null;
    }
```

This code works fine and I am getting null value in frontpage variable. but when I am rewriting the function as

```
protected override Task<WordDocument> GetFrontPage() => null;
```

I am getting an `NullReferenceException`.

Could anyone help me to understand the difference between the two statements.?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Could anyone help me to understand the difference between the two statements.?

Your first declaration is `async`, so the compiler generates appropriate code to make it return a `Task<WordDocument>` which has a result with the result of the method. The task itself is not null - its *result* is null.

Your second declaration is *not* `async`, therefore it just returns a null reference. Any code awaiting or otherwise-dereferencing that null reference will indeed cause a `NullReferenceException` to be thrown.

Just add the `async` modifier to the second declaration and it'll work the same as the first.

Note that there are no lambda expressions here - your second declaration is an *expression-bodied method*. It just uses the same syntax (`=>`) as lambda expressions.

Answer (score 0):

try with:

```
Func<Task<WordDocument>> frontPage = async () => await GetFrontPage();

protected override async Task<WordDocument> GetFrontPage() => await Task.FromResult<WordDocument>(null);
```

Comment: `protected override Task<WordDocument> GetFrontPage() => Task.FromResult<WordDocument>(null);` shorter and less overhead

Answer (score -1):

This works for me:

```
    protected override async Task<WordDocument> GetFrontPage() => await Task.FromResult<WordDocument>(null);
```

Comment: `protected override Task<WordDocument> GetFrontPage() => Task.FromResult<WordDocument>(null);` shorter and less overhead